# How can I integrate YouTube payment details into my website using the YouTube API?

Tags: api, youtube-api, payment, implementation

I developing a website which need to integrate payment detail of YouTube. how to I integrate YouTube all payment details history in my website. I need a code for this.
Any tutorials ?After the authentication I need to send the comment, like to specific videos

Comment: What payments are you referring to?